# APscheduler and Pyramid python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pyramid, python-multithreading, apscheduler

I'm trying to use the wonder apscheduler in a pyarmid api. The idea is to have a background job run regularly, while we still query the api for the result from time to time. Basically I use the job in a class as:

```
def my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_result = 0
        scheduler = BackGroundScheduler()
        scheduler.start()
        scheduler.add_job(my_job,"interval", id="foo", seconds=5)
    def my_job():
        print("i'm updating result")
        self.current_result += 1
```

And outside of this class (a service for me), the api has a POST endpoint that returns my_class instance's current result:

```
class MyApi(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.my_class = MyClass()

     @view_config(request_method='POST')
     def my_post(self):
        return self.my_class.current_result
```

When everything runs, I see the prints and incrementation of value inside the service. But **current_result** stays as **0** when gathered from the post.
 From what I know of the threading, I guess that the update I do is not on the same object **my_class** but must be on a copy passed to the thread.
One solution I see would be to update the variable in a shared intermediate (write on disk, or in a databse). But I wondered if that would be possible to do in memory.

I manage to do exactly this when I do this in a regular script, or with one script and a very simple FLASK api (no class for the API there) but I can't manage to have this logic function inside the pyramid api.

It must be linked to some internal of Pyramid spawning my api endpoint on a different thread but I can't get right on the problem.

Thanks !

=== EDIT ===

I have tried several things to solve the issue. First, the instance of MyClass used is intitialized in another script, follow a container pattern. That container is by default contained in all MyApi instances of pyramid, and supposed to contain all global variables linked to my project.
I also define a global instance of MyClass just to be sure, and print its current result value to compare

```
global_my_class = MyClass()
class MyApi(object):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
     @view_config(request_method='POST')
     def my_post(self):
        print(global_my_class.current_result)
        return self.container.my_class.current_result
```

I check using debug that MyClass is only spawned twice during the api execution (one for the global variable, one inside the container. However.
So what I see in logging are two values of *current_result* getting incremented, but at each calls of *my_post* I only get 0s.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of view class only lives for the duration of the request - request comes in, a view class is created, produces the result and is disposed. As such, each instance of your view gets a new copy of `MyClass()` which is separate from the previous requests.

As a very simple solution you may try defining a global instance which will be shared process-wide:

```
my_class = MyClass()

class MyApi(object):

    @view_config(request_method='POST')
    def my_post(self):
       return my_class.current_result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I edited the question. I already tried that, and in fact, I don't instanciate myClass at each intialization of MyApi by default. I suspect that the reason lies somewhere in a processing issue. Quite frustrating to go on Flask for just that :)